# How to validate 2 fields by comparing them after a specific character

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate 2 fields after a specific charachter:

```
<input id="email" class="txt" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" size="25" name="email"></input>
<input onblur="alexa()" id="domain" class="txt" maxlength="255" value="" size="25" name="domain" type="text">
```

I know that for validating them you do smth like this this

```
function BothFieldsIdenticalCaseSensitive2() {
 var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var three = document.getElementById('domain').value;
```

I know that comparing them simply one value from a field with the other would be smth like

```
 if(two == three) { return true; }
 alert("Warning!! passcodes must match!!!");
 return false;
}
```

But i need to know:

// how do you ask it to compare the 2 fields after the character "@", and if the characters matches after that char then return true; else { alert (Please add the website e-mail address in order to register (webmaster@domain.com)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `split` func on the char `@`:

```
var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
var three = document.getElementById('domain').value;

var first = two.split("@")[1]; //[1] to get the part after the split char
var second = three.split("@")[1];

//Compare
if (first == second)
    console.log("They match!");
```

Comment: It seams that it doesn't take them properly, it still takes and compare them simply not after the char have a look http://www.blowppc.com/ppc-publisher-registration.php. Enter webmaster@domain.com on e-mail and on Domain enter domain.com it works only if i add same characters on both. BTW here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76XNX/2/

Comment: @Adrian -- If I enter `xx@gmail.com` and `www.gmail.com` respectively, it compares out to `true`, is this right?

Comment: If you enter like that the user should not get any messages. If you enter xx@gmail.com and www.domain.com should echo the message. The fact is that it works if i enter in the e-mail field domain.com and in the domain field domain.com. Same. But doesn't split the char.

Comment: @Adrian -- It won't split the `domain.com` in the email field because it is looking for the `@` symbol and not finding it.

Comment: So where am i mistaking?

Comment: I don't think anywhere. If a user enters a domain in the email field its obviously wrong.

Comment: Got it 50% added var second = three.split("www.")[1]; instead of var second = three.split("@")[1]; but now the user will need to enter the domain with www. it won't work without www.

Comment: Got it, IT's like this: var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
var three = document.getElementById('domain').value;
var first = two.split("@")[1]; //[1] to get the part after the split char
var second = three.split("www.")[1];
//Compare
if (first == three || first == second)
{ return true;}
    else { alert('Please enter the e-mail of the domain'); return false;}
}

Answer (score 1):

```
function BothFieldsIdenticalCaseSensitive2() {
    var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var three = document.getElementById('domain').value;

    var twoIndexOfAt = two.indexOf("@");
    var threeIndexOfAt = two.indexOf("@");
    var match = twoIndexOfAt !== -1 && 
        threeIndexOfAt !== -1 &&
        two.substring(twoIndexOfAt + 1) === three.substring(threeIndexOfAt + 1);

    if (match) { 
        return true; 
    }
    else {
        alert("Warning!! passcodes must match!!!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but does the same thing as tymeJV. Somehow it doesn't skip the characters after "@".